# Input lag when changing layoutX & layoutY on an ImageView using keyboard input

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

My use case is the following:

```
Given an ImageView element, move that around the Pane by using keyboard UP/DOWN/LEFT/RIGHT buttons. 
The ImageView should by cycling between different images and the source images 
will change when movement is detected.
```

I am using two different AnimateTimers for that. The first one is used to "cycle" through a list of Images and update given list when movement is detected.

```java
public class MultipleImageListAnimation extends AbstractAnimationTimer {

    @Getter
    private final SimpleObjectProperty<Image> imageProp;
    @Getter
    private final SimpleIntegerProperty scaleProp;
    private volatile List<List<Image>> spriteImagesLists;
    private volatile List<Image> displayedImageList;
    private int imageIndex = 0;
    private int listIndex = 0;

    public MultipleImageListAnimation(List<List<Image>> spriteImagesLists) {
        super(1);
        this.imageProp = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        this.scaleProp = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1);
        this.spriteImagesLists = spriteImagesLists;
        this.displayedImageList = spriteImagesLists.get(0);
        if (displayedImageList.size() > 0) {
            super.setFramesPerSecond(displayedImageList.size() * 2);
        }
    }

    public void changeSpriteImages(List<List<Image>> images) {
        this.stop();
        this.spriteImagesLists = images;
        this.listIndex = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(images.size());
        this.imageIndex = 0;
        this.displayedImageList = images.get(listIndex);
        super.setFramesPerSecond(displayedImageList.size() * 2);
        this.start();
    }

    public void setScaleProp(int angle) {
        scaleProp.set(angle);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(long now) {
        // shouldRun() is a typical FPS method
        if (shouldRun(now)) {
            Image image = displayedImageList.get(imageIndex);
            imageProp.set(image);
            if (++imageIndex >= displayedImageList.size()) {
                listIndex = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(spriteImagesLists.size());
                displayedImageList = spriteImagesLists.get(listIndex);
                imageIndex = 0;
                super.setFramesPerSecond(spriteImagesLists.get(listIndex).size() * 2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second one is updating the layoutX & layoutY properties of the image.

```java
        new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                int xDelta = playerMovementListener.getXDeltaAndReset();
                if (xDelta != 0) {
                    playerImageView.setLayoutX(playerImageView.getLayoutX() + xDelta);
                }
                int yDelta = playerMovementListener.getYDeltaAndReset();
                if (yDelta != 0) {
                    playerImageView.setLayoutY(playerImageView.getLayoutY() + yDelta);
                }
            }
        }.start();
```

Those are updated through an EventHandler as shown below

```java
public class PlayerMovementListener implements EventHandler<KeyEvent> {

    private final GameViewManager gameViewManager;
    // Using a Set of keys because I want to detect diagonal movement as well such as UP + LEFT etc.
    private final Set<KeyCode> keysPressed;
    private final AtomicInteger xDeltaCounter;
    private final AtomicInteger yDeltaCounter;

    public PlayerMovementListener(GameViewManager gameViewManager) {
        this.gameViewManager = gameViewManager;
        this.keysPressed = new HashSet<>();
        this.xDeltaCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
        this.yDeltaCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    }

    public int getXDeltaAndReset() {
        return xDeltaCounter.getAndSet(0);
    }

    public int getYDeltaAndReset() {
        return yDeltaCounter.getAndSet(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if (KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED.equals(keyEvent.getEventType())) {
            keysPressed.remove(keyEvent.getCode());
            // Stopping movement on any key released
            // This is fine for now.
            gameViewManager.stopPlayerMoving();
        } else if (KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED.equals(keyEvent.getEventType())) {
            keysPressed.add(keyEvent.getCode());

            if (KeyCode.RIGHT.equals(keyEvent.getCode())) {
                gameViewManager.rotatePlayerAnimation(1);
            }

            if (KeyCode.LEFT.equals(keyEvent.getCode())) {
                gameViewManager.rotatePlayerAnimation(-1);
            }

            if (Arrays.asList(KeyCode.UP, KeyCode.DOWN, KeyCode.RIGHT, KeyCode.LEFT).contains(keyEvent.getCode())) {
                yDeltaCounter.addAndGet(MovementInput.getLayoutYDelta(keysPressed));
                xDeltaCounter.addAndGet(MovementInput.getLayoutXDelta(keysPressed));
                gameViewManager.startPlayerMoving();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the relevant methods of the `GameViewManager`

```java
public class GameViewManager {

    private AnchorPane gamePane = ...;
    private PlayerEntity playerEntity = ...;
    private ImageView playerImageView;
    private MultipleImageListAnimation playerAnimationTimer;
    private boolean isPlayerMoving = false;

    public void startPlayerMoving() {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            if (!isPlayerMoving) {
                isPlayerMoving = true;
                playerAnimationTimer.changeSpriteImages(List.of(playerEntity.getRunImages()));
            }
        });
    }

    public void stopPlayerMoving() {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            if (isPlayerMoving) {
                isPlayerMoving = false;
                playerAnimationTimer.changeSpriteImages(List.of(playerEntity.getIdleImages()));
            }
        });
    }

    public void rotatePlayerAnimation(int angle) {
        playerAnimationTimer.setScaleProp(angle);
    }

    private void initializeKeyboardListeners() {
        PlayerMovementListener playerMovementListener = new PlayerMovementListener(this);
        gameScene.setOnKeyPressed(playerMovementListener);
        gameScene.setOnKeyReleased(playerMovementListener);

        new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                // This is executing constantly, I know of the implications but it's good for now
                int xDelta = playerMovementListener.getXDeltaAndReset();
                if (xDelta != 0) {
                    playerImageView.setLayoutX(playerImageView.getLayoutX() + xDelta);
                }
                int yDelta = playerMovementListener.getYDeltaAndReset();
                if (yDelta != 0) {
                    playerImageView.setLayoutY(playerImageView.getLayoutY() + yDelta);
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void initializePlayerImageView() {
        this.playerImageView = new ImageView();
        playerImageView.setLayoutX(STARTING_WIDTH);
        playerImageView.setLayoutY(STARTING_HEIGHT);
        playerAnimationTimer = new MultipleImageListAnimation(Arrays.asList(playerEntity.getIdleImages()));
        playerAnimationTimer.start();

        playerImageView.imageProperty().bind(playerAnimationTimer.getImageProp());
        playerImageView.scaleXProperty().bind(playerAnimationTimer.getScaleProp());
        gamePane.getChildren().add(this.playerImageView);
    }
}
```

---

Now this approach is working fine for my use case. However I can't help but notice that there is a very slight but noticeable "lag" when an input key is pressed and until the View actually moves. I can see that the images are cycled to the "running" state immediately but the sprite is not moving until later.  Once it does there is no more lagging on processing the input. Releasing the key and pressing another one displays the same lag at the start of movement. [You can see a recording of this behavior here](https://imgur.com/a/Se0awZH). I do not know what's causing this and how I can fix this so any input is appreciated.

---

Edit: The AbstractAnimationTimer class

```
  public abstract class AbstractAnimationTimer extends AnimationTimer {

    public long now;
    protected long FPS_BREAKPOINT;

    public AbstractAnimationTimer(int framesPerSecond) {
        this.now = 0;
        this.FPS_BREAKPOINT = 1_000_000_000 / framesPerSecond;
    }

    protected void setFramesPerSecond(int framesPerSecond) {
        this.FPS_BREAKPOINT = 1_000_000_000 / framesPerSecond;
    }

    public boolean shouldRun(long now) {
        if (now - this.now > this.FPS_BREAKPOINT) {
            this.now = now;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

---

Edit 2: Reproducible example

```java
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Main extends Application {

    private final Set<KeyCode> keysPressed = new HashSet<>();
    private final AtomicInteger yDeltaCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private final AtomicInteger xDeltaCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 800);
        scene.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                keysPressed.clear();
            }
        });
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED.equals(keyEvent.getEventType())) {
                    keysPressed.add(keyEvent.getCode());
                    if (Arrays.asList(KeyCode.UP, KeyCode.DOWN, KeyCode.RIGHT, KeyCode.LEFT).contains(keyEvent.getCode())) {
                        yDeltaCounter.addAndGet(getLayoutYDelta(keysPressed));
                        xDeltaCounter.addAndGet(getLayoutXDelta(keysPressed));
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        primaryStage = new Stage();
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100);
        rect.setFill(Color.RED);


        new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                // This is executing constantly, I know of the implications but it's good for now
                int xDelta = xDeltaCounter.getAndSet(0);
                if (xDelta != 0) {
                    rect.setLayoutX(rect.getLayoutX() + xDelta);
                }
                int yDelta = yDeltaCounter.getAndSet(0);
                if (yDelta != 0) {
                    rect.setLayoutY(rect.getLayoutY() + yDelta);
                }
            }
        }.start();

        pane.getChildren().add(rect);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static int getLayoutXDelta(Set<KeyCode> keysPressed) {
        int xDelta = 0;
        if (keysPressed.isEmpty()) {
            return xDelta;
        }
        if (keysPressed.contains(KeyCode.RIGHT)) {
            xDelta += 10;
        }
        if (keysPressed.contains(KeyCode.LEFT)) {
            xDelta -= 10;
        }
        return xDelta;
    }

    public static int getLayoutYDelta(Set<KeyCode> keysPressed) {
        int yDelta = 0;
        if (keysPressed.isEmpty()) {
            return yDelta;
        }
        if (keysPressed.contains(KeyCode.UP)) {
            yDelta -= 10;
        }
        if (keysPressed.contains(KeyCode.DOWN)) {
            yDelta += 10;
        }
        return yDelta;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably off-topic, but Lombic `@Getter` etc do not work correctly with JavaFX properties (they will not create the correct methods). Implement the JavaFX Property pattern directly in code (your IDE may have ways to generate the code automatically for you).

Comment: What is `AbstractAnimationTimer`? This is not a JavaFX library class.

Comment: Why the calls to `Platform.runLater(...)` and the `AtomicInteger`s, etc? I don't see any multithreading here.  Everything in the code you posted is already being called on the FX Application Thread.

Comment: What do you mean by your comment `// This is executing constantly`?

Comment: I just don't think there is anywhere near enough information in the question to help diagnose the issue. The obvious guess would be that the delay is coming from the `if (shouldRun(now))` clause, which seems to explicitly delay movement. But there's no way to tell because you haven't posted that method. You need to create and post a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: That said... I don't quite understand your strategy for movement here. When a key is pressed, I'm guessing `deltaX` or `deltaY` are set by the key event handler. But on the next frame rendering you set those back to zero (in the animation timer). So there will be a very small movement for *each* key press. What you want is smooth movement *while the key is down*. So I think what you are seeing is multiple small movements from the system keyboard repeat. The lag is the delay from keyboard repeat which is deliberately built in at the system level.

Comment: Basically, get rid of everything that is not related to movement, including the sprite animation. (Probably by writing an application entirely from scratch.) Just move a shape around a pane using the basic strategy you have here. I think you will see the same result. Then post that as a [mre].

Comment: @James_D I have updated the question including the AbstractAnimationTimer code. shouldRun() is a typical limiting method so the Animation doesn't execute 30k times per second. Removing the method call entirely doesn't correct the issue but it shouldn't anyway. The method is updating the sprite which is working as expected and I think is not relevant for the issue.

Comment: Please create a [mre] as requested.

Comment: @James_D Added reproducible example. On this example I can also see that the Rectangle "lags" behind a bit at start. I think it may be caused by what you mentioned earlier, `So I think what you are seeing is multiple small movements from the system keyboard repeat. The lag is the delay from keyboard repeat which is deliberately built in at the system level.`. How do I fix that?

Comment: I think I see the issue now. If I modify the code as following for a condition                     `if (KeyCode.UP.equals(keyEvent.getCode())) addTop = true;` and then on the AnimationTimer I do this `if (addTop)  yDelta -= 10;` then the animation becomes much smoother. If you can post an answer to this question so that I can approve it along with an explanation of _why_ this is happening I will be glad. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As others have said, the use of volatile, AtomicInteger, and shouldRun seems suspect.  It implies you may be running your own animation loop (possibly even as a spin loop) which you should not do.  No loops are needed to perform your animation, and you should not need any additional threads.

Comment: I don't know what `playerEntity.getRunImages()` and `playerEntity.getIdleImages()` do.  I assume that they get a list of cached, preloaded images rather than loading new images each time.  If that is not the case, then that could be another source of delay.

Comment: @jewelsea Correct, those methods are simple getters that are retrieving pre-loaded assets. The issue with my approach is explained clearly by James D answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your animation timer sets `deltaX` and `deltaY` back to zero when it uses them:

```
    new AnimationTimer() {
        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            // This is executing constantly, I know of the implications but it's good for now
            int xDelta = xDeltaCounter.getAndSet(0);
            if (xDelta != 0) {
                rect.setLayoutX(rect.getLayoutX() + xDelta);
            }
            int yDelta = yDeltaCounter.getAndSet(0);
            if (yDelta != 0) {
                rect.setLayoutY(rect.getLayoutY() + yDelta);
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

They will only be made non-zero again when the key listener is invoked, i.e. when the appropriate keys are pressed again. Consequently, the rectangle moves 10 pixels in the appropriate direction *for each key press*.

What you really want is for it to move continuously *while the key is held down*.

The reason it appears to move repeatedly is because of the operating system's keyboard repeat, which sends multiple key press events if a key is held down. There is a delay on this, which is why you see a delay before the rectangle starts repeatedly moving. (If you observe closely, you will see one isolated movement when the key is first pressed, then the delay, then the repeated movement.) You'll also notice the movement is not smooth, because it is moving in 10 pixel increments at discrete times (which are determined by the operating system, so it will move at different speeds on different systems).

The correct strategy for this is simply to keep track of which keys are down, and then to calculate the amount of horizontal and vertical movement in the animation timer depending on those keys. You probably want to make the amount of movement dependent on the amount of time since the last animation frame, so that you can accurately control the speed.

Note that since everything is on the same thread, there is no need at all for `AtomicInteger` etc.

Here is a working solution that implements these ideas:

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main extends Application {

    private final Set<KeyCode> keysPressed = new HashSet<>();
    private static final double SPEED = 200.0 ; // pixels per second

    private Point2D delta = Point2D.ZERO;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 800);
        scene.setOnKeyReleased(keyEvent -> keysPressed.remove(keyEvent.getCode()));
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(keyEvent -> keysPressed.add(keyEvent.getCode()));

        primaryStage = new Stage();
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100);
        rect.setFill(Color.RED);


        new AnimationTimer() {
            private long lastUpdate ;

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                long elapsedNanos = now - lastUpdate;
                double elapsedSeconds = elapsedNanos / 1_000_000_000.0;
                delta = getDelta(elapsedSeconds);
                rect.setLayoutX(rect.getLayoutX() + delta.getX());
                rect.setLayoutY(rect.getLayoutY() + delta.getY());
                lastUpdate = now;
            }
        }.start();

        pane.getChildren().add(rect);
        primaryStage.show();
    }



    public Point2D getDelta(double elapsedSeconds) {
        double distance = SPEED * elapsedSeconds;
        int xDelta = 0 ;
        int yDelta = 0 ;
        if (keysPressed.contains(KeyCode.LEFT)) xDelta--;
        if (keysPressed.contains(KeyCode.RIGHT)) xDelta++;
        if (keysPressed.contains(KeyCode.UP)) yDelta--;
        if (keysPressed.contains(KeyCode.DOWN)) yDelta++;
        return new Point2D(xDelta, yDelta).normalize().multiply(distance);
    }
}
```

Just to demonstrate that the movement (from one `AnimationTimer`) is completely independent of the sprite animation in your original (defined in another `AnimationTimer`), the following snippet will mimic the sprite animation (alternating colors while the rectangle moves, instead of alternating images). Just add this in the `start()` method.

```
    // alternate colors while moving:
    new AnimationTimer() {
        private long lastUpdate ;
        private final Color[] colors = new Color[] {Color.BLUE, Color.RED};
        private int currentColor = 0 ;

        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            if (delta.equals(Point2D.ZERO)) {
                currentColor = 0;
            } else {
                long elapsedNanos = now - lastUpdate;
                double elapsedSeconds = elapsedNanos / 1_000_000_000.0;
                if (elapsedSeconds > 0.25) {
                    currentColor = (currentColor + 1) % colors.length;
                    lastUpdate = now;
                }
            }
            rect.setFill(colors[currentColor]);
        }
    }.start();
```